# How to stream huge data from DB to client

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, openjpa

I would like to store huge binary data in a database.
Clients should be able to inspect metadata like content size, creation date etc
as well as to stream the content.

Using JPA, persisting meta data is straightforward.

```
@Entity
public class MyData {
    @Id
    private String name;
    private Timestamp creationDate;
    private long contentSize;
```

But how to model the content?
If I would use

```
byte[] content;
```

then the full content must be held in memory, which is unwanted.

With Hibernate, the following works, but other JPA-Providers, eg openJPA,
complain that `content` is neither persistent nor annotated `@Transient`.

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private java.sql.Blob content;
```

Question: Is there a portable solution that allows for streaming
without the need to hold the whole content in a byte array?

Comment: Portable? nope. Nothing in the JPA spec for that. All JPA providers have their own supported types, and supported ways of handling them. As you say "byte[]" isn't a suitable type, but then neither is Blob since it is tied to a JDBC driver being present. Something like Reader or InputStream make more sense ... if your JPA provider supports them

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using JPA on its own or with Spring.  If it is with Spring then have a look at [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content)?  This library provides an abstraction for handling content (including huge content as the API is based on streams) that is portable across Storage; RDBMS, File, S3, Mongo's GridFS.  In the case of RDBMS it does the work hard of managing the stream in a memory efficient way so you can lazy stream the content back to the calling client (outside of an open DB connection).  Might be worth a look.